# Converting Column1 value as header and column2 as its value in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I am Trying to convert the Column 1 as Header name of the data frame and Column 2 value as its respective values:

Eg :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([(10,'foo'), (20,'bar')])
```

Resulted data frame will have :

```
   0    1
0  10  foo
1  20  bar
```

Expected data frame :

```
 foo bar
0 10 20
```

I am new to Python and looking the help in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: is it that you already have the dataframe, or you just have the list??

Comment: do you only have 2 data points as above or very many data points?

Comment: I have many data points.  I am already having dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `zip` and sequence unpacking:

```
L = [(10, 'foo'), (20, 'bar')]
*data, headers = zip(*L)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)

print(df)

   foo  bar
0   10   20
```

If you have a pre-existing dataframe `df_input`, your first step can be rewritten:

```
*data, headers = zip(*df_input.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
L = [(10,'foo'), (20,'bar')]
df = pd.DataFrame([{j:i for i, j in L}])
print (df)
   bar  foo
0   20   10
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have many data points I would assume something like the following with the assumption that `bar` always comes after `foo`

```
L = [(10, 'foo'), (20, 'bar'),(30,'foo'),(40,'bar'),(5,'foo'),(5,'bar')]
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

Then you can do:

```
df.assign(idx = df[1].eq(df.iloc[0,1]).cumsum()).pivot('idx',1,0)

1    bar  foo
idx          
1     20   10
2     40   30
3      5    5
```